# Can I track requested pages/files from 'index.php'?

Tags: php, html, request

Let's say I have a website, `www.someweb.com`, and there I have the file `index.php` that contains index code, etc.

Then I have two folders: `f1` and `f2` at `www.someweb.com/f1/` and `www.someweb.com/f2/`. Now if the user requests `www.someweb.com/f1/somefile.abcd` I want to increment a counter. If the user visits `www.someweb.com/f2/somefile2.abcd` some other file in other folder with the same extension I want that counter to be incremented again.

Whenever user requests that page, I want to print the current counter value. Example:

```
www.someweb.com/f1/somefile.abcd // counter = 1
www.someweb.com/f2/somefile2.abcd // counter = 2
www.someweb.com/f1/somefile.abcd // counter = 3
```

etc.

How do I do it?

Comment: Do you mean the end user should see the counter? Or are you just trying to get analytics for your own purposes?

Comment: yes i just want to see if its possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what server log information is for.  Use any freely available server log analysis tool.

You could also define a global server environmental variable on you web server and increment it with each request server.  This would in essence be a little script running in your web server environment.

Comment: thank you i will try to do this later. i have no experience with any server log analysis tools so i'll do little research on them.

Answer (score -2):

Store the counter in a session. Then you can increment it and print it from the session object.

Comment: yes but how do i know which file was requested, somefile.abcd extension can not have php code inside can it ?

Comment: If he wants a global counter of all requests coming to those subdirectories, this would not work.

Comment: yes global counter of all requests to any file that can be stored in any directory with the extension of .abcd

Comment: no, these files are not even run by the PHP engine, they are being called directly from apache, assuming apache is what you are using.

Answer (score -2):

You would need to call `session_start()` to track it correctly, making it a requirement that the files being tracked be PHP.

The only way I could think of would be to write a PHP function to parse your Apache log to print out the statistics you want.

Comment: PHP sessions would have nothing to do with counting all requests against a web server.